# Select Parameter Anomaly

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

This is driving me crazy, and even though it doesn't really matter right now I'd like to know what's going on.

I have a Stored Procedure called ClientSelect:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Client
```

That's all that's in it (I've stripped it right back to try and figure out what's going on!)

I also have an ASP.NET page with a GridView.  Its DataSource looks like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLClient" runat="server"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestDBConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="EXEC ClientSelect" >
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ClientID" Type="Int32"  />
        </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Note that the SelectCommand does not make any reference to the SelectParameter, and the Stored Procedure does not ask for any parameters.  This page loads, but the GridView is empty - no data returned.

However, if I remove the SelectParameter completely, or add a default value so that it looks like:

```
<asp:Parameter Name="ClientID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="1"  />
```

It returns all the records in the table (not filtering by the specified default value).

Why is the explicit coding of a SelectParameter causing no data to be returned, even though neither my SelectCommand or my Stored Procedure are making any reference to it at all?  It doesn't make sense to me!

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this ??

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLClient" runat="server"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestDBConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="ClientSelect" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" >
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ClientID" Type="Int32"  />
        </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not a specialist about ASP.NET, but I see, that if your SP doesn't have any parameters, but still you specify them on the query - it should throw an exception, unless you've turned this kind of exceptions (SQL SERVER) off.

Besides, if there is a parameter specified, but no value applied, it also causes an error, because normally any code is transformed by the driver you access the SQL Server into the T-SQL code. So in the first time you will get this:

EXEC ClientSelect @ClietntId=

And next one is that

EXEC ClientSelect @ClietntId=1

which is ok.
Well, people say if there are parameters specified, that are not exist, they are ignored. DefaultValue should be. Otherwise its better to try code @Dhaval suggested and give a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify a way to get the actual value for the defined parameter.

For example; if you are getting parameter value from a session variable you have to define your SelectParameter as

```
<!-- To get ClientID from a session variable called myClientId -->
<asp:SessionParameter Name="ClientID" DbType="Int16" 
                      DefaultValue="0"  SessionField="myClientId"/>

<!-- To Get ClientID from a dropdown List called ddlClients -->
<asp:ControlParameter Name="ClientID" DbType="Int16" 
                      DefaultValue="0" ControlID="ddlClients"/>


<!-- YOUR CODE -->
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLClient" runat="server"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestDBConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="ClientSelect" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" >
        <SelectParameters>
            <!-- Add correct parameter type as appropriate -->
        </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Good point about leaving out the SelectCommandType value - I've added it in now, though it didn't have any effect on the behaviour. I know my sample code suffers from being an artificial example, but you wouldn't specify that the parameter was from a query string or session variable if you had a control within the data control (e.g. FormView) bound to field with that name, which I would if this was a real page. Then again, if there was such a bound control then I guess there would necessarily be a default value so it would probably work.

Comment: In practice I guess this anomaly would never actually crop up, but since I was just messing around with a dummy page it did, and I was curious as to why.

Comment: Even though it was bit odd, I wasn't also sure about the effect of defining `SelectCommandType` or using `SelectCommand="EXEC spName"` without defining it. So I removed it..